# openSUSE. How to route traffic using two different Networks

Tags: networking, internet, kde, opensuse

My system details:

- openSUSE 12.3 KDE.
- I have a Wifi card and an ethernet card.
- I subscribe to two internet connections from two different companies:

  - Company A provides 2MBps unlimited bandwidth.
  - Company B provides 20MBps limited bandwidth. 20GB a month.

I want some apps like Radiotray to connect to internet using network card with configuration  to connect to internet using Company A network.

I want Firefox and Chrome and other apps to connect to Internet using network card with configuration to connect to internet using Company B network.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Using squid servers to detect streaming content would work but you would need another box with squid to tell your desktop squid to cache-peer to company B.   Seems overly complex for a single box.